# limit execution time of shell_exec

Tags: php, fatal-error, shell-exec

I have an exe file which has the following code:

**while(1)**

**printf("hello\n");**

I'm executing this exe through php using shell_exec

**$output = shell_exec('C:/Users/thekosmix/Desktop/hello.exe 2>&1');**

**echo $output;**

now the script is executing for very long time untill i kill the process from task manager and it gives fatal error:

**(Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 133693440 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\shell\index.php on line 7)**

I want the script (or this function) to run for a given time duration and print whatever output is generated during the time-duration not any fatal error. set_time_limit() is also not solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this from within PHP - [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) is only checked after each PHP statement gets executed. Under linux you'd use `ulimit`, but it looks like you're using Windows.

You'll need to either modify the `hello.exe` executable to build in a timeout, or write a wrapper that you call from PHP, which call `hello.exe` and handles the timeout. In any language that can easily fork, this is trivial.

Comment: using ulimit, how can i solve my problem?? I'm new to linux...so don't have exact idea how to use ulimit...!

Comment: `ulimit -t 3` sets the current process to only be allowed 3 seconds of CPU time. the process will be killed when this time limit is reached. Bear in mind this is CPU time, not real time.

Comment: u mean i can do this..

shell_exec('ulimt -t 3');
shell_exec($path_to_program);

Comment: can you please tell me how to set the time limit in shell_exec in linux using php

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up: do the following, if you use a Linux server:

```
shell_exec('ulimit -t 120 && ' . $path_to_program);
```

This terminates after two minutes of cpu-usage, which is a lot more than 2 minutes real time depending on the resources hunger of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could alter the script as so

```
while (shouldKeepRunning())
```

shouldKeepRunning could, in its most crude form, check for whether a certain file exists to determine if it should keep running. Then you just create or delete a file to shut the script down gracefully. On linux, you could use a signal handler for this, but not windows. Anyway, you get the point.

you could use ticks if the outer while loop isnt granular enough without massive code modifcation. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php